# replace tabs with "" in R dataframe

Tags: r, replace, tabs, gsub

I have a large dataframe (df) that has a couple of unwanted tabs. I need to replace those tabs with an empty string so my parsing will work.

I have tried the following and neither works:

```
df[ df == "\t" ] = ""  (tried both "\t" and "\\t")

df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\t", "", x)))

df<- data.frame(apply((df),MARGIN = 2,function(x){gsub("\\t","",x,fixed = TRUE)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: `gsub("\t", "", "abc\tdef")` works.  You do not need two backslashes.

Comment: I would not have expected two backslashes to succeed (and I'm also surprised to see that a single one is acceptable), rather using three backslashes would have seemed the "correct" approach.

Comment: I realized when I read the file using   temp <- read.delim(file="file.txt",header = F), it splits at the tab. I am not able to use delim = "\:  ", that would solve the problem. How can I read the file either removing the tab during the read or to read the whole file and then remove the tab using the commands above?